# get user email from firebase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to display the user email as a string from my auth variable. In the first image below, I declare the auth variable. The second image is what I get when I console.log(auth). How do I get the user email and other info?  I tried various combinations of console.logs and mostly get null.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) has a section called "Get a user's profile" that explains the same. Try the following:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const email = user.email;
    console.log(email)
  } else {
    console.log("User not logged in")
  }
})
```